# error: ‘calloc’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, malloc, archlinux

I am compiling my code using `g++` in `arch linux`

Getting this error while compiling.
`.error: ‘calloc’ was not declared in this scope`

I have not tried to compile this code in `ubuntu` but i am quite sure that it will pass.So is this a problem related to `arch linux` or some thing wrong with my code

Here is my code :

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
class Graph
{
    private :

    unsigned int numNodes;
    class Connection
    {
        public :
        int to;
        int weight;

        Connection (int to,int weight)
        {
            this->to = to;
            this->weight = weight;
        }
        Connection (int to)
        {
            this->to = to;
        }


    };

    Connection **nodeList;

    public :

    Graph (unsigned int numNodes)
    {
        this->nodeList = calloc (sizeof (Connection*),numNodes);
        this->numNodes = numNodes;
    }   

};
```

Comment: use a `std::vector`. that said, to find the header that declares any given function, look in the **documentation**.

Comment: [`#include <stdlib.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc)

Comment: why teach someone to fish when you can give person a ready broiled fish

Comment: lol...this is not any assignment....i making my own C++ stl like library...

Comment: @PRP Nice! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::calloc` function is defined in `<cstdlib>`. You need to include it in order to fix this error.

With this said, you would be better off using `operator new` - an idiomatic way of allocating dynamic memory in C++.

And you would be even better off (much better off) using `std::vector` instead of using raw pointers and `new`.

Comment: i am making a graph library in c++....there are some disadvantages using new...also i have implemented my own vector library....https://github.com/MadaraUchiha-314/Data-Structures-Library.....thanx for telling the error......